# Use Typescript in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to write this code:
`.map(({ key }) => key);` using typescript, i did this: `.map(({ key:any }) => key);`, but i got an error: `'any' is declared but its value is never read.`. How to apply typescript in my situation?

Comment: yes it will be because in this case `{ key:any }` any will be treated as alias of key. use it something like this `{ key }: { key: any }`

Comment: `arrayData.map(({ key, value }: any) => {
      console.log("***", key, value);
 });

Answer (score 2):

What you do is destructing argument and assign property to new value, instead you should do this:

```
.map(({ key }: { key: any }) => key);
```

I would suggest to read more about TS in [handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
const array: any = [{ test: 10 }, { test: 'test' }, {test: true}];
console.log(array.map(({ test }: {test: any}) => test));
```

output :
[10, "test", true]